# The function $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}$, its inverse and summation

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics, polylogarithm, inverse-function

I am reading the more understandable mathematics in the section **Preliminary Results** of a paper in which the authors give a explanation of facts for the **logarithmic integral and its inverse.** In this post I ask about similar equations but now for a different logarithmic integral function, now I consider $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}$, and its inverse $\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)$. My goal is understand more these facts (the genuine computations from the authors), and refresh basics about analysis. I know the relation between a function that has inverse, its graph, the function $x$ and the inverse function (I write this because could be useful to find the asyptotic that I ask in my question, I don't know how deduce it now).

I can write and know that
$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\sim\frac{(1+o(1))x}{\log^2x}\quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

but,

> **Question 1.** Can you give the correspoding and similar asymptotic for $\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)$, as $x\to\infty$? Here, as I've said $\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)$ is **the inverse function of the logarithmic integral** $\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}$.

I know that by **differentiation of a inverse function** and by the **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus** I can write my explanation for a similar equation for $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ (following the equation that the authors write for the logarithmic integral)

$$\left(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}\right)'\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2t}\right)}=\log^2x,$$

and **combining this last with the composition with** $\mathrm{Li}^{-1}_2(x)$ one has the coresponding equation and compute $\left(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}\right)'(x)$ as 
$$\left(\mathrm{Li}^{-1}_2\right)'\left(\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)\right)\right)=\log^2\left(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)\right).$$

> **Question 2.** Can you use the asymptotic that you've computed as answer of **Question 1**, to get an asymptotic as $x\to\infty$ for $\log^2\left(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(x)\right)$?

I believe, following similar computations that authors give for their logarithmic integral function, that now I with $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ can write

$$\sum_{1<m<n}\mathrm{Li}^{-1}_2(x)=\int_2^{\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(n)}\frac{tdt}{\log^2t}+O\left(\sum_{1\leq m\leq n}\log^2 m\right).$$

> **Question 3 (Now this question is optional, thus 
>   it is not necessary to answer).** I say that I've asked to me if previous identity is right when I write the similar statement for which I believe that holds. Can you refute previous statement? Can you prove it using previous answers to my questions (I believe that with these the authors can prove their identity), or at least give a reasonable approximation for other methods (I say perhaps partial summation)?

Comment: Can you give the source of the paper? In *The n-th prime asymptotically* (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.5413) Arias de Reyna and Toulisse
give some understandable results for asymptotoc expansions of $\mathrm{li}^{-1}(x)$. But I guess this is not your source, because the is no *preliminary results* section.

Comment: I am editing the question to improve in the sense to ask only two question. The third question now is optional, this is, isnt' neccesary give an answer, but of course hints and answers will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You get $Li_2^{-1}(y)\sim y\log^2 y$ and derivative $\sim \log^2 y$. You can easily verify correctness by plugging this back in the expressions you already have.

Comment: You last equality can be shown by taking considering $\frac {\Delta LHS}{\Delta RHS}$ and using already derived expansions.

Comment: PLease @A.S. you are welcome to provide us a detailed answer, that could be useful for a wide audience. Thanks.

Comment: Write $\frac x{\log^2 x}\sim y$. What does $x$ have to be? Clearly it must have $y$ in it - but then the LHS is being divided by $\log^2 y$. Compensating by $y\log^2 y$ gives correct asymptotic equality. Then you just differentiate it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your many remarks, and try to do the ccomputaions . Moreover, I have no English as native language and I seeking refresh many math facts, so it is always better for me, the answer more detailed answer to understand more, since I can find in it more useful things written in mathematical language. You are welcome if you want give it @A.S. But I can say you many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\sim\frac{(1+o(1))x}{\log^2x}\quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

Means that

$$\log(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))\sim \log\left(\frac{(1+o(1))x}{\log^2x}\right)\quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

therefore we also have

$$\log(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))\sim \log((1+o(1))x)-\log(\log^2x)\quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

$$\log(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))\sim \log(x)-2\log(\log x)+\log(1+o(1)) \quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

$$\log(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))\sim \log(x)-2\log(\log x)+o(1) \sim (1+o(1))\log(x) \quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

$$\log^2(\mathrm{Li}_2(x)) \sim (1+o(1))\log^2(x) \quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

This means that

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\sim\frac{(1+o(1))x}{\log^2x} \sim \frac{(1+o(1))x}{\log^2(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))}\quad\text{  as }x\to\infty,$$

And hence $$(1+o(1))x \sim \mathrm{Li}_2(x) \log^2(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))$$

Rewriting gives $x \sim (1+o(1))\mathrm{Li}_2(x) \log^2(\mathrm{Li}_2(x))$.

Substitute $x=\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(y)$ in to get

$$\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(y) \sim (1+o(1))y \log^2(y)$$

---

This also means that:

$$\log(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(y)) \sim \log((1+o(1))y \log^2(y)) \sim (1+o(1))\log(y)$$

$$\log^2(\mathrm{Li}_2^{-1}(y)) \sim \log((1+o(1))y \log^2(y)) \sim (1+o(1))\log^2(y)$$

Comment: If there are any steps unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: VERY THANKS MUCH, @wythagoras, I am studying your proof, very thanks much to you and previous user **A.S.**,It is now reference for all us.

Comment: It is a **masterpiece of clarity**, thanks for all details.